# AngularJS: increase decrease div height with smooth animation

Tags: css, angularjs, css-animations

i was trying to increase decrease div height with smooth animation but fail to do so due to good command over css animation.

### here is my code

```
<body ng-app="ang_app" ng-controller="ang_control01_main">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="myCheck">
    <div id="myDiv" ng-show="myCheck" class="animate-show animate-hide"></div>
</body>

var app=angular.module('ang_app', ['ngAnimate']);
    app.controller('ang_control01_main', function($scope) {

});
```

### CSS

```
.animate-hide {
-webkit-transition:all linear 1s;
-moz-transition:all linear 1s;
-ms-transition:all linear 1s;
-o-transition:all linear 1s;
transition:all linear 1s;
}

#myDiv {

    transition: .5s;
    background-color: lightblue;
    height: 100px;
}

#myDiv.ng-hide {
    transition: .5s;
    height: 0;
}
```

please check this site https://codepen.io/LFeh/pen/ICkwe must watch how they nicely  increase decrease div height when we hover and out pointer from div. how to achieve the same smooth effect in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to work fine - are you sure that you have included a script reference to `angular-animate.js`? Here is a working sample of your expand and collapse transitions:

```js
angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate']);
```

```css
.animate-hide {
  transition: all linear .5s;
}

#myDiv {
  background-color: lightblue;
  height: 100px;
}

#myDiv.ng-hide {
  height: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.4/angular-animate.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="app">
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="myCheck">
  <div id="myDiv" ng-show="myCheck" class="animate-hide"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: what is the meaning of this line `transition: all linear .5s;` ?

Comment: this style added to ng-hide then how it is working when showing div? because when div is showing then a animation is playing with div. plzz guide.

Comment: The `transition` property in my example indicates that transitions should be applied to all CSS property changes (`all`) using a constant rate of change (`linear`) taking one half second (`.5s`). Both adding and removing `.ng-hide` are considered property changes so both are animated.

Comment: You add transition to animate-hide class not animate-show. Show how it is getting applied when increasing div hide not clear to me. Plzz help

Comment: The `.animate-hide` class is just a CSS class - it doesn't actually have anything to do with the `ngAnimate` stuff. You could just as easily have put the `transition` property on the `#myDiv`, but putting it on a class gives you more flexibility to use it on other elements.

Comment: your code is running i checked in SO but when i paste your code in jsfiddle then it is not working with animation. here my jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/tridip/bkg3g59z/   can u plzz check what is missing here.

Comment: Two issues: 1) You were trying to load both Angular 1.4.8 and Angular 1.6.4; 2) You used `app.controller`, but you never created a variable named `app`. Here is a [fixed jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bkg3g59z/1/).

Comment: in angular we have to do animation always with css ? is there any other because developer most of the time may not have good command over css. so what they can do if they like to do animation..........?